# check if tab with defined text in gtk.notebook exists +gtk3

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, glade

Is there a function to check if there is a Tab in a gtk.notebook with a defined text? Just found the function "get_menu_label_text ()", but it just returns the text of the tab from it's transmitted child.

Just want to find out if there is a already created tab, so I don't have to create it again.

Really simple, but can't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need such function as the developer should know what goes on the notebook and as such, it becomes "trackable".

Anyway, there are some approaches, like getting the number of pages with [`get_n_pages()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Notebook.html#Gtk.Notebook.get_n_pages), getting the child for the n page with [`get_nth_page()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Notebook.html#Gtk.Notebook.get_nth_page) in a for loop and invoking the Gtk.Notebook [`get_tab_label_text(child)`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Notebook.html#Gtk.Notebook.get_tab_label_text) method.

Another option would be using the Gtk.Container [`foreach`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Container.html#Gtk.Container.foreach) method (Gtk.Notebook inherits from Gtk.Container) and iterate by all child(s) and get the tab label text and compare it with the search text.

The following, very simple, example creates a two page notebook with unreferenced text labels and then we simply verify if some label exists in the Notebook tab labels.

Example:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Simple Notebook Example")
        self.set_border_width(3)

        self.notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
        self.add(self.notebook)

        self.page1 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page1.set_border_width(10)
        self.page1.add(Gtk.Label('This is Gtk.Notebook Page X'))
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label('Page X'))

        self.page2 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page2.set_border_width(10)
        self.page2.add(Gtk.Label('This is Gtk.Notebook Page Y'))
        self.notebook.append_page(self.page2, Gtk.Label('Page Y'))

    def check_exists_tab_with_label(self, label):
        self.notebook.foreach(self.check_label_for_child, label) 

    def check_label_for_child(self, widget, label):
        if (self.notebook.get_tab_label_text(widget) == label):
            print ("FOUND")

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
win.check_exists_tab_with_label('Page Y')
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: yeah you're right, but I was wondering if there is a easy solution for that. The "foreach" method is quite awesome and fits in many other approaches too, thanks alot!